# Java reconstructing byte array index ranges into new byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I am trying to create a brand new byte array from an existing byte array. My `existingBtyeArray` has `metadata1` from index 0 - 16, and `metadata2` from index 16 - 33 and then the remaining would just be called `remaining`, lets say it goes from index 33 to 100. Right now the byte array is order like this:

```
existingBtyeArray = metadata1 (0 - 16) + metadata2 (16 - 33) + remaining (33 - 100)
```

I would like to move `metadata2` to the end of remaining in a new byte array so something like this:

```
newByteArray = metadata1 + remaining + metadata2
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using `System.arraycopy` to copy a part of array.

```
public static byte[] reconstruct(byte[] arr){
    byte[] result = new byte[arr.length];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, result, 0, 16); //copy metadata1 
    System.arraycopy(arr, 33, result, 16, arr.length-33); //copy remaining 
    System.arraycopy(arr, 16, result, 16 + arr.length-33, 33-16); //copy metadata2 
    return result;
}
```